# AutoHotkey map F12 to make four keystrokes

Tags: autohotkey

67-year-old grannie here. My 12-year-old programmable keyboard died and I will try to use AutoHotkey in its stead to do simple keyboard macros. Here's the first one I need to create. When I press F12, I want it to send these keystrokes to Audacity (but it could be any program; the keystrokes are simply shortcut keys to do specific functions):
Alt+G
S
Enter
Enter

How would I program that in AutoHotkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly straightforward:

```
F12:: ;When F12 is pressed
Send !g ;Press Alt+g
Send s ;Press s
Send {Enter 2} ;Press Enter Twice
return ;End this hotkey
```

(Note: Anything after a semicolon is a comment)

When tested in Audacity, it properly generates a default length clip of silence, then deselects the created audio segment.

---

Bonus:

Add `#IfWinActive ahk_exe audacity.exe` to the top of the script to make the hotkey only activate if Audacity is the active window.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! Straightforward to those of you who know what you're doing. I would have spent 3 frustrating days trying to figure this out with no guarantee of success.

Comment: Glad I could help @Eweforia! If this solution solved your question, could you please mark it as the accepted answer?